# PHP/MYSQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying for day to get the following code to work. When running it no SQL or PHP errors occur and it just runs smoothly.

BUT neither a new record is inserted nor old records are updated.

The basic function is reading a csv file and importing it into a MYSQL database.

```
<?php
//DB connect
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "adm", "???", "ip-miniapps");
//DB connection check
if (!$db) {
    $txt = "\r\nupdate_cron.php - ".date("y-m-d");
    $txt .= "\r\nError: Can't connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    $txt .= "\r\nDebug-Fehlernummer: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    $txt .= "\r\nDebug-Fehlermeldung: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    $myfile = file_put_contents('/www/website_ip-miniapps/scripts/executables/update_cron.log', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    exit;
}

//START - update routine for table app_all_supplier_master_data
if (($handle = fopen("/www/website_ip-miniapps/interfaces/SAP/supplier_md.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
        //remove excess field
        while(count($data)>13)
        {
            array_pop($data);
        }
        //mysqli-real_escape_string
        $i=0;
        while($i<=12)
        {
            $data[$i]=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data[$i]);
            $i++;
        }
        $line = implode("','", $data);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `app_all_supplier_master_data` (`supplier_code`,`name_1`,`name_2`,`street`,`zip`,`city`,`country`,`ekorg`,`supplier_node`,`node_name`,`classification`,`gbc`,`gbc_name`) VALUES('";
        $query .= $line;
        $query .= "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                  `supplier_code`='{$data[0]}',
                  `name_1`='{$data[1]}',
                  `name_2`='{$data[2]}',
                  `street`='{$data[3]}',
                  `zip`='{$data[4]}',
                  `city`='{$data[5]}',
                  `country`='{$data[6]}',
                  `ekorg`='{$data[7]}',
                  `supplier_node`='{$data[8]}',
                  `node_name`='{$data[9]}',
                  `classification`='{$data[10]}',
                  `gbc`='{$data[11]}',
                  `gbc_name`='{$data[12]}'";
        mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    }
fclose($handle);

}
//END - update routine for table app_all_supplier_master_data

//DB close
mysqli_close($db);

$txt = "\r\nupdate_cron.php - ".date("y-m-d")." - Success";
$myfile = file_put_contents('/www/website_ip-miniapps/scripts/executables/update_cron.log', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

I echoed $query, but can't see anything.

```
INSERT INTO `app_all_supplier_master_data` 
(`supplier_code`,`name_1`,`name_2`,`street`,`zip`,`city`,
`country`,`ekorg`,`supplier_node`,`node_name`,`classification`,
`gbc`,`gbc_name`) 
VALUES('Vendor','Name 1','Name 2','Street','PostalCode','City',
    'Cty','POrg','Hi.lv.hier',
    'Vendor number of higher-level','Preisausz.','PGr',
    'Description') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `supplier_code`='Vendor', 
    `name_1`='Name 1', 
    `name_2`='Name 2', 
    `street`='Street', 
    `zip`='PostalCode', 
    `city`='City', 
    `country`='Cty', 
    `ekorg`='POrg', 
    `supplier_node`='Hi.lv.hier', 
    `node_name`='Vendor number of higher-level', 
    `classification`='Preisausz.', 
    `gbc`='PGr', 
    `gbc_name`='Description'
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @ManiSingh **Didnt you read the question?** It says _When running it no SQL or PHP errors occur and it just runs smoothly._

Comment: can you `echo  $query` then see if your query is valid? and you also need to check for errors

Comment: I know it's not save, but it's an import script for an Intranet application interface with SAP.

Comment: WHERE is `$line` DEFINED

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$line = implode("','", $data);` before the `$query`

Comment: @AndreasW after you echoed `$query` do u see a correct sql statements? can u paste the results of `echo $query`

Comment: Posted in original post echo $query at the bottom

Comment: Looks like you forgot to SKIP the first line of the file containing the Column TITLES. I would guess there is something there that is of the wrong datatype to fit in the Database column definition

Comment: The real data contains confidential information, but the script is running past the first line.

Comment: Did you add the error reporting code yet and run script again?

Comment: I get this now:
Notice: Undefined offset: 12 in /www/website_ip-miniapps/scripts/executables/update_cron.php on line 33

Comment: On one hand you have `while(count($data)>13) { array_pop($data); }` so $data is a 12 elements array, on other hand you have `$i=0; while($i<=12) {` so you have 13 iterations on this (12 elements) array.

Comment: I think you're wrong because $data is a 13 elements array 0-12.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself thank you for the support. I compared the raw data from the CSV file to the Structure of the DB table.

The problem was the data I wanted to add was formatted wrong for example.

My key column is supplier_code (VARCHAR(6)) but the data I tried to add was "0000400000"

So I simply trimmed of the excess zeros and it worked.

Comment: Good to see it's solved. How did you find this was the issue? Pease update your answer to show *how* you discovered this. Thanks.